# Parsely.js override default validation messages

Tags: javascript, validation, overriding, message, parsley.js

Does anyone here know how you can override validation messages during setup.

I would like to be able to during setup $('form').parsley() to change/define validation messages messages for lets say:

data-parsley-required-message ="some relevant custom message"

I want this to be assigned to all validations so if the field is set to required it will display the custom message as default.

Thanks in advance 8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [in the documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-field) for `window.ParsleyUI.updateError(parsleyInstance, name, message);`.

This is assuming version 2, if you are still on 1.X let me know and I will amend the answer.

Comment: You could also define it in a global window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.en.required="Your message" before calling Parsley. It would replace globally the value in ParsleyValidator